# Как открыть ссылку в Safari

Tags: safari, instagram, href

В профиле инстаграма можно указать ссылку на сайт, она активна. При клике на нее сайт загружается в окне браузера инстаграма. Как сделать так чтобы ссылка открывалась в Safari?

Делал прослойку в виде редиректра. Никак не выходит. На Хром могу перекинуть, на сафари нет